# How to find out whether TDD is strictly followed in a project?

Tags: tdd

These days we follow TDD across projects in the company. How as a leader I will know whether TDD is truly followed within a project? I would like to achieve this through automation that is instead of manually auditing, would like to see some tool to monitor the developers workbench constantly and alert if TDD approach is not followed

Comment: A TDD approach is taken because of the end result (i.e. coverage, reduced bug count, certain design decisions) - are you seeing these end results? As an aside - I think I'd hate to work for you. Automating this level of micro-management is a fantastic way to cripple creativity and kill your dev team's morale. It's also entirely unnecessary.

Comment: As much as I would love to automate this, there is no metric that would work. Only way is to talk with people and motivate them to value TDD. So they can extert peer pressure.

Comment: Speak to your developers. Even if such tooling exists, why even bother deploying it when you know there is a risk not everybody is on board?

Comment: "monitor the developers workbench constantly and alert if TDD approach is not followed" 
I value the TDD approach; that said - please don't do that, that just misses the point.

Comment: This is impossible. If the developer thinks of a design in his head before writing the test, then he is not doing TDD, because the test doesn't drive the design. How are you going to measure whether the developer thought about the *test* before writing the test (which is okay) or thought about the *solution* before writing the test (which is not okay)?

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to audit that something that *superficially looks like TDD* was followed, by requiring every change be committed to a branch before any code is run.

Your automation tool will then replay commits and observe a "red - green - refactor" cycle. However it's highly likely it will miss times when *more than the minimum* is done each cycle. It will also give you no indication of the *true value* of tests written.

To *successfully* audit that *only* TDD occurred, you will need a review process that takes as much or more effort than the original development, metaphorically looking over the shoulder of each developer. As other commenters have noted, this is likely to cripple morale and productivity.